# Strange memory usage when using unmanaged memory

Tags: c#, unmanaged

Our application needs to call a certain unmanaged 3rd party library via interop. The application is heavily threaded and calls into this function a few thousand times a minute which is why it's critical that we don't leak memory.

When running the application on our servers, I noticed that the memory footprint of the application was increasing and after weeks of navigating the issue, I finally narrowed it down to this very strange problem:

I'm observing a very strange behaviour when working with unmanaged code in that, after allocating and deallocating unmanaged pointers, the memory does not seem to go down as expected.

This is a minimal code to reproduce the problem:

```
Platform: x64
Build: Release (optimised)
Windows Server 2012
64GB memory
Dual Xeon processors with 64 logical cores
<gcServer enabled="true />
```

And the code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // LargeFile.abc is representing a byte[] of ~300kb
        byte[] largeArray = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Data", "LargeFile.abc"));
        TestMemoryAllocation(largeArray);

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void TestMemoryAllocation(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        Parallel.For(0,
            1000000,
            i =>
            {
                FromStream(byteArray, ptr =>
                {
                    // simulate some work with the unmanaged pointer
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                });
            });
    }

    private static void FromStream(byte[] src, Action<IntPtr> func)
    {
        IntPtr unmanagedArray = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            // allocate the memory on the unmanaged heap
            unmanagedArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(src.Length);

            // do something with this unmanaged pointer
            func(unmanagedArray);
        }
        finally
        {
            // free the space
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Normally, my expectation would be that depending on the number of cores and the threading schedules, the memory would go up and down but would eventually be stable and hover between a minimun and a maximum. Instead, this is what I'm observing:

The private working bytes keeps increasing in ProcessExplorer/TaskManager (this is a Windows server) and the memory profilers (using ANTS and JetBrains dotMemory) both report an increase in the memory consumption during the runtime.

This is a screenshot of dotMemory when running the application until it finishes:
[image]

The line in red is what is actually happening (when running the above code sample) whereas the line in blue is what I *expect* it to look like.

I've also tried adding/removing GC pressure (GC.Add/RemoveMemoryPressure) and that didn't help but that's understandable since there's no GC happening here. And I tried the same thing on a Window 10 desktop but observed the same behaviour.

What is going on? Our server controls memory usage by process and if the memory exceeds a certain level, it kills and restarts the process which means we have to be careful with our memory usage and need to be able to control this.

Update: Graph with Thread.Sleep(0) instead of Thread.Sleep(50):

[image]
Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, doing a bit of memory analysis on your test code (mind, I increased the allocation to 100x to get there faster :):

1. No GC ever happens. This is not surprising, since you're not really allocating much managed memory - after a minute (when I get an out of memory crash), the heap has grown by something like 10 kiB, no reason for the GC to kick in.
2. I get *forty worker threads* (on a 4-core CPU). This is also not too surprising, but might be the cause of your problem. When you're using synchronous code that doesn't do enough CPU work, the worker thread pool will increase the thread pool to accomodate more concurrent workloads. It doesn't care about how much memory you're using. This means that if your threads don't finish faster than new are spun up, your memory usage is going to keep increasing until the process crashes.

Check how many threads are running on your server as the memory increases. The jumps in usage seem to follow the new worker threads being created quite nicely. Note that you have a mere `Thread.Sleep(50)` in the code, which limits the maximum number of threads you get; I expect your real workloads may take a lot more than that.

So, in my opinion, it's not really a leaking memory problem - it's a throttling problem. You can fix this issue by having a system that limits how many threads you allow to be used for this particular problem. In your test application, this is as simple as:

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000000, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 },
  i =>
  {
    FromStream(byteArray, ptr =>
    {
       // simulate some work with the unmanaged pointer
       Thread.Sleep(50);
    });
  }
);
```

Voilá - your memory usage reaches a peak and remains stable. Tweak the degree of parallelism to suit how much work you can actually do in parallel and how much memory you have available.

Comment: Thank you very much for this analysis Luaan. We did test the number of threads some time ago and it wasn't increasing beyond 200 on the server, 32 of which were named threads for the purpose of this particular call. I'll have a look again and put in performance counters that tick every few minutes to give me the thread statistic. With regards to our actual program, we use 32 event loop schedulers from RX.Observables and those are the ones that actually call into this 3rd party system.

Comment: Unless there's a bug in RX (possible of course), I can't see how more than 32 threads could enter this but everything's possible but I think you're correct, hence the accepted answer. The problem goes away with limiting the number of threads so that must be it. Thank you again.

Comment: @kha There might be some issues in your production code that are unrelated to what I found in the sample code, of course; I would definitely recommend adding a few performance counters to track the allocations and deallocations you're making. If they're matched (and the number of memory allocated at any time isn't too different from what you see in task manager), you might be having issues with memory fragmentation, for example. Also, if you're using fixed byte arrays in your production code (through `MemoryStream`), you might get serious managed heap fragmentation.

Comment: @kha You can very easily see them with CLRProfiler - just take a full memory dump of the process when it's showing the issue, and look at the heap in CLRProfiler - if you see most of the memory unused, you're having fragmentation issues; Marc's suggestion of using `ArrayPool<byte>` will make your troubles go away in that case.